# why ruby code of adding c extension in is not working?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, inline-code

```
require "rubygems"
require "inline"

class Primes
  inline do |builder|
    builder.c '
    int prime(int num) {
    if (num == 2){ return 1;}
    if (num %2 == 0) {return 0;}
    int i = 3;
    while( i * i <= num)
    {
          if (num % i==0 )
          {
           return 0; 
           }
          i = i+2;
     }
     return 1;
    }'
  end
end

p = Primes.new

for num in 2..10_000 do
   is_prime = p.prime(num)
   if is_prime == 1
      puts "#{num} is a prime number"
   else
      puts "#{num} equals #{is_prime} * #{num/is_prime}"
   end
end
```

while executing this piece of  ruby code i am getting lot of errors ...

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:96: warning: else without rescue is useless
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:108: warning: else without rescue is useless
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
            when nil: @position = length-1
                     ^
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
            when 0: @position = length-1 if @cycle
                ^
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:105: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
            when nil: @position = length-1
                     ^
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:106: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
            when length-1: @position = 0 if @cycle
                ^
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:106: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
            when length-1: @position = 0 if @cycle
                          ^
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/inline-0.1.0/lib/inline/history_buffer.rb:128: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    end
       ^
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using some old version of that gem that is abandoned. There is never version created by SeattleRb team and called [`RubyInline`](https://rubygems.org/gems/RubyInline). Check this out.